# Scraping HTML-page using readHTMLTables in R

Tags: r, xml-parsing, web-scraping

I'd like to scrape this webpage: http://unbisnet.un.org:8080/ipac20/ipac.jsp?&menu=search&aspect=power&npp=50&ipp=20&spp=20&profile=bib&index=.TW&term=%22draft+resolution%22&index=.AW&term=Netherlands

I need to create a dataframe containing five columns (title, imprint, enhanced title, UN document symbol, publication date) for each resolution. I tried using readHTMLTables, but I can't seem to figure it out. The website contains many tables. When I run my code I get a list with 394 objects, but to me it seems they are all empty.

```
u <- "http://unbisnet.un.org:8080/ipac20/ipac.jsp?&menu=search&aspect=power&npp=50&ipp=20&spp=20&profile=bib&index=.TW&term=%22draft+resolution%22&index=.AW&term=Netherlands"
tables = readHTMLTable(u)
names(tables)
length(tables)
tables[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your approach. That's a horrible site with many, many deeply nested `<table>`s. Here's one way to deal with it, but you'll have to roll up your sleeves to get all the fields you may want. *Please* research `XPath` queries or post specific follow-up "how to"'s for this as separate questions (i.e. how to target a specific XPath element) vs tack on to this post.

We'll use the Hadleyverse:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
```

This reads in the HTML from the page:

```
doc <- html("http://unbisnet.un.org:8080/ipac20/ipac.jsp?&menu=search&aspect=power&npp=50&ipp=20&spp=20&profile=bib&index=.TW&term=%22draft+resolution%22&index=.AW&term=Netherlands")
```

At some point in the deeply nested structure there's a `<table>` with one `<tr>` and two `<td>` elements that have the field and then the data for the field. One way to get the data for the value field is to target the label field (which is in an `<a>` tag), go up one level (to the `<td>`) then take it's next sibling (the value `<td>`). For example, to get all the `Title:` values:

```
titles <- xml_text(
            html_nodes(doc, 
              xpath="//td/a[starts-with(., 'Title:')]/../following-sibling::td[1]"))
```

You can do the same for these three fields:

```
imprints <- xml_text(html_nodes(doc, xpath="//td/a[starts-with(., 'Imprint:')]/../following-sibling::td[1]"))
un_doc_sym <- xml_text(html_nodes(doc, xpath="//td/a[starts-with(., 'UN Doc')]/../following-sibling::td[1]"))
pub_date <- xml_text(html_nodes(doc, xpath="//td/a[starts-with(., 'Publication Date')]/../following-sibling::td[1]"))
```

and wrap them all in a `data_frame` / `data.frame`:

```
unbisnet <- data_frame(titles, imprints, un_doc_sym, pub_date)

glimpse(unbisnet)

## Observations: 50
## Variables:
## $ titles     (chr) "Draft resolution [on establishment of an Internati...
## $ imprints   (chr) "[New York] : UN, 29 July 2015", "[New York] : UN, ...
## $ un_doc_sym (chr) "S/2015/562", "A/69/L.80", "A/69/L.78", "A/69/L.76"...
## $ pub_date   (chr) "20150729", "20150715", "20150630", "20150625", "20...
```

Targeting some of the others won't be as easy but it's doable.